# time scale in NetLogo / remove turtle

Tags: time, netlogo, hour

I would like to build a system which has time scale of minutes and hours

there are number of turtles which stay in specific patches for different time based on their types then leave.

I use data-and-time as a property of turtle to record arrive time then calculate the leaving time

but i don't know how can I make the turtle reaches this leaving time ( after 4 to 6 hours)

also I got confused to  deal with hours and  minutes scale ? as the turtles will arrive at any time between the morning and the midday , stay for a period of time based on their type then leave

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest equating one tick with one minute, and doing all your calculations in minutes.